# Probability of Barcelona playing Real Madrid in Champions League Quarterfinals

Tags: probability

The $2018$ Champions League quarterfinal draw will take place on Friday, March $16^{th}, 2018$ and I wanted to know what is the likelihood that *Barcelona* will get paired up with *Real Madrid*? There are $8$ teams left in the pool so a total of $4$ draws will be made.

I think that the number of ways to pairing *Barcelona* v *Real Madrid* is $^8C_2$ but I am stuck on how many possible **draws** there are. Isn't it $\dfrac{^8C_2}{\text{total # of draws}}$?

If someone can walk me through the solution to this problem that would greatly be appreciated. Probability has always given me trouble...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it would be helpful to think as follows: Given that the Real madrid ball has been drawn, what is the probability that the Barcelona ball will be drawn? Of course it is $1/7$.

By way of more explanation: Count the number of possible quarter finals as follows: fix a team, Real, the number of teams this team can play is then 7, so there are 7 possible quarter final matches Real can play. Real Madrid-Barcelona is one of these potential 7.

It may help to try this tactic with a semifinal and convince yourself.

Comment: But Real Madrid's ball doesn't have to be the first one picked. I feel like there is some conditional probability involved.

Comment: indeed, we are exploiting some symmetry in the problem. The probability of any team playing another team should be the same, so it suffices to consider Real Madrid being drawn first.

Answer (score 4):

Barcelona is going to play each of the other $7$ teams with equal probability so the answer is $\frac{1}{7}$